# When I resize the browser, my h1 doesn't adjust and just stays in the same place and disappears when the browser gets too small

Tags: html, css

Here's my code. I'm a beginner so please let me know if I have any errors.
I need to have the text resize and move when the browser is scaled. As of now it just stays and doesn't move no matter the size. I've tried a media query's but they haven't worked.

```css
html{
 background-image: url(images/CBG1.png);
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

h1{
 text-align: -webkit-center;
 color: #FF6633;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-left: 650px;
 margin-top: 314px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Hoax Studios</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta charset="uft-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="work.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div class="header">
    <h1>WORK</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not moving because you have it positioned as absolute relative to the browser. it's not scaling because youre not doing anything with the font-size. For the font-size, try setting it to something like font-size 10vh;

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the alignment and width for h1 as below

```
h1 {
     color: #FF6633;
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-top: 314px;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;  
    }
```

Comment: `-webkit-center` would only work for webkit browsers and is not for general use. I don't know why anyone would need it at all. You should explain how your markup actually solves the problem.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing out, I missed to remove that line earlier.